# Iphone Deployment Target with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I'm having an issue trying to use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions) libraries in my iPhone application.

When I go to compile my project for the iPhone Simulator 3.0 SDK, I get the following error:

```
Too few arguments to function 'CFNetworkCopyProxiesForAutoConfigurationScript'
```

After a bit of search around the web I found some indications that it may be related to my [iPhone Deployment OS target as referenced in this blog post](http://blog.tofodo.com/2009/09/watch-out-for-iphone-deployment-target_6228.html)  I followed the posts instructions and updated my iPhone OS Deployment Target to iPhone OS 3.0, but I still seem to be hitting the wrong branch of the `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` in the ASIHTTPRequest.m file which is causing the argument errors I believe.

Any ideas on what exactly my issue is and how to fix it so I can actully compile my code with ASIHTTPRequest included?

[This other StackOverflow question may also solve my problem potentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031682/how-do-you-set-iphone-os-version-min-required) but it has no answers yet.

Answer (score 1):

Ran in to this same problem.
As it turns out it was as of a side effect of another framework as identified in this time-sink averting post

http://tofodo.posterous.com/be-careful-when-using-custom-iphone-framework